# Jira - Access-Control-Allow-Origin fo JS

Tags: jira

Is there anybody to talk developers of Jira about a problem:

https://snipboard.io/SJH1DK.jpg

https://snipboard.io/rHhOGk.jpg

I load the page from project atlassian.net

and the scripts are failed:

https://jsd-portal-frontend.us-east-1.prod.public.atl-paas.net/assets/servicedesk-vendor.chunk.3dde037493978045057b.js

https://jsd-portal-frontend.us-east-1.prod.public.atl-paas.net/assets/servicedesk-vendor.chunk.3dde037493978045057b.js

https://jsd-portal-frontend.us-east-1.prod.public.atl-paas.net/assets/servicedesk-customerportal.bundle.2526e99080a9017eee30.js

Comment: Can anybody answer this question or advice? Or just wait for a thumb down?)

Answer (score 0):

OK

I just install

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=en-US

and now the page is loading without problems

It's a temporary decision for me as user